# Sync Linux to Windows 2003/2008 Natively

Tags: linux, windows, time

Without using any external packages for Windows, can Linux synchronise it's clock to a Windows 03/08 Server natively? I've tried it using various NTP packages for Windows but would like to use just Windows software for this.

EDIT: I've tried the below however it doesn't work. I've put `TimeSource` in `/etc/hosts`, stated `server TimeSource` in `/etc/ntp.conf` however when I do a `service ntpd start` it doesn't sync (it's 3 minutes out at the minute). I then stopped the NTPD and did a `ntpdate TimeSource`, thinking it would sync and then I'd start the NTPD once it's got the time, and it says: *no server suitable for synchronization found*. Though I can ping it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "net" command from the linux box:

```
net time set -S <server>
```

Answer (score 2):

PDC (Primary Domain Controller) works as a NTP server - you can simply point your Linux box to it. If you want to configure it outside of Active Directory, the process is a bit different: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/configure-a-standalone-ntp-server-in-windows-server/3869

Cheers.
siupakabras

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a Linux client's `ntpd` (or other NTP clients like `ntpdate`) has no problem syncing its clock with the NTP server mode of the Windows Time Service.